# How can I get the squares of numbers less than and including 5 without the multiplication and power operators?

Tags: while-loop

I can only use a `while` loop, `+=`, `<=`, `==`, `+`, `-`.

And it is recommended to use the odd difference between the square numbers.

**Example**

input
`5`

output
`1, 4, 9, 16, 25`

Comment: How are 1 and 4 between 5 and 25?

Comment: its the square numbers in between 1-5, like 2^2 = 4, 4^4= 16, 5^5 = 25

Answer (score 0):

You can add (2*n +1) to the previous square and get the next square in case you do not want to use squaring at all.

Here is a sample python script.  Change the value of N to modify the range. You can also make  it a function to input N.

```
N=5
a =1;
increment=3;
print (a)
for i in range (1,N) :
    a= a + increment
    print (a)
    increment = increment +2;
```

Please let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: what if 2*n is not allowed?

Comment: Then make a variable called increment and initialize to 3. Each time increase the increment by 2.  Add this value to previous number.

Comment: could you please show me in code?

Comment: I added a piece of code, Pleas check.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously inelegant due to the operator restrictions:

```js
const squares = (n) => {
  let multiplier = n ;
  let square = 0;
  
  while (0 <= --multiplier) square += n;
  
  let i = 1;
  let inc = 3;
  
  while (i <= square) {
    console.log(i);
    i += inc;
    inc += 2;
  }
}

squares(5);
```

First just use a while loop to calculate the square of the number, and then another while loop to get all the squares up to that number.